# dispatch: function expect two parameters while my function doesn't

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm working on a little thing.
I'm trying redux-toolkit for that.
Right now i'm exporting this function

```
export const fetchItems = (): AppThunk => async dispatch => {
        dispatch(getItems())

        try {
                const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/items")
                const data = await response.json()

                dispatch(getItemsSuccess(data))
        } catch (error) {
                dispatch(getItemsFailure())
        }
}
```

And try to use it somewhere else with a simple

```
dispatch(fetchItems())
```

and I get this as an error

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 0.  TS2554.

I looked in the console what was the type of my function `fetchItems`. It is seen as a "create_reducer". To be honest i don't understand what's going on and I would love somebody
explain to me what is a mistake and what is going.

Comment: The error should be `Expected 0 arguments, but got 2` because you defined fetchItems to receive no parameters but you are passing 2 parameters.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to put the correct version back. I actually stated putting parameters to try to guess what was the function expecting to get when i was debugging.